# When plotting the predicted results from a svycoxph object, how can you tell which curve is which?

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I used [svycoxph](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/4.2-1/topics/svycoxph) from the survey package to create an object based on a complex survey design:

```
object <- svycoxph(Surv(time, status) ~ group, design=design)
```

And then I used predict() as documented [here on page 88](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf) to predict curves and plot them:

```
prediction <- predict(object, type="curve", newdata = data.frame(group=c("A", "B")) )

plot(prediction[[1]],ci=FALSE,col="sienna") 
lines(prediction[[2]],ci=FALSE,col="royalblue")
```

My group variable is a factor with levels A and B. Is list 1 A and list 2 B? I assumed this was the case, but the results are the opposite of what I expected. When I open the object in the source pane, there is no labeling beyond list 1 and 2 (no A or B labeled anywhere).

Is there any way the curves got flipped? Are the results possibly listed alphabetically instead of in factor order?

Comment: if you want to verify which group each estimate is running from you can do this in predict : `prediction <- predict(object, type="curve", newdata = data.frame(group=c("A")) )` then do the same for B, after finding estimates you can combine the predict statement and re-label as needed

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this. Thank you.

Comment: It produces an error for only having 1 level

Comment: I'll try again tomorrow but make sure you have the most up to date packages and I will also post my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, I didn't get any errors for having only one level. I am using the example in survey and just modified the predict statement.

```
library(survey)
library(survival)
 
 data(pbc, package="survival")
 pbc$randomized<-with(pbc, !is.na(trt) & trt>0)
 biasmodel<-glm(randomized~age*edema,data=pbc,family=binomial)
 pbc$randprob<-fitted(biasmodel)
 if (is.null(pbc$albumin)) pbc$albumin<-pbc$alb ##pre2.9.0
 dpbc<-svydesign(id=~1, prob=~randprob, strata=~edema, data=subset(pbc,randomized))
 rpbc<-as.svrepdesign(dpbc)
 
 (model<-svycoxph(Surv(time,status>0)~log(bili)+protime+albumin,design=dpbc))
 svycoxph(Surv(time,status>0)~log(bili)+protime+albumin,design=rpbc)
 s1<-predict(model,se=TRUE, type="curve",
            newdata=data.frame(bili=c(3), protime=c(10), albumin=c(3.5)))
 s2<-predict(model,se=TRUE, type="curve",
             newdata=data.frame(bili=c(9), protime=c(10), albumin=c(3.5)))
```